# Sublime Text: Search List of Opened Files and Focus

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime using `Command + T`, I'm able to list all the files in the project and then open the one that I want.

Is there a shortcut key to also search only the list of already opened files and then focus it

Reason: When I have very similar named files, it is easier to only search the already opened files (I would only have to deal with a small subset of files)

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Goto%20Tab

Comment: @KeithHall should have posted as a answer

Comment: @KeithHall Thanks. But I was not able to find GoTo Tab in package installer, probably it is not supporting ST3. I found Tab Filter package to do the job.

Answer (score 8):

You can jump to files and function using Goto Anything: `Ctrl + P`. It will open the palette to input your search.

Answer (score 6):

Found that the Tab Filter package does what I wanted. I am able to search from within the already opened tabs

[Tab Filter in Package.io](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Tab%20Filter)

[Tab Filter in GitHub](https://github.com/robinmalburn/sublime-tabfilter)